# (LINUX SUSE) Can't copy a folder to paste it to my LINUX directory located in my Desktop. Says "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, suse

I have this activity in school which I've been working on for a few days now. I was able to create a folder but the next step which is to "Copy the folder USR Located in the ancestor directory then paste it to your Desktop Directory using Absolute Referencing." doesn't seem to work. The code I used is:

```
cp -r usr /home/root/Desktop/LINUX
```

[Here's the steps I need to do but I already failed step 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC8oT.png)

[The second part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVKfR.png)

If you can help me with these steps, it'd be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using relative referencing (`usr`) when you were asked to use absolute referencing (for example `/home/root/directory/usr`)? Are you sure the target directory exists and you have permission to access it? Is your username `root`?

Comment: The second step says relative referencing. And yes the target directory exists and I'm using root.

Comment: Is the directory `usr` in the current directory? Do you see it when using `ls`? You can change the current directory with `cd`.